# NetSuite Advanced PDF/HTML - Get rid of Currency Symbol before Rate

Tags: html, pdf, netsuite, symbols, suitescript

How would I go about getting rid of the currency symbol that NetSuite outputs on the printed form?

```
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
```

Instead of €3.00, I want to output 3.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer...

```
${record.rate?html?replace("€","")}
```

Comment: what if we have multiple currencies?

Comment: I have used this successfully and recently getting an error on save of the template. I note that Freemarker has depreciated html and it appears my error is generated with " being substituted by &quot;

Syntax error in template "content". Encountered "&", but was expecting one of:.     <STRING_LITERAL>.     <RAW_STRING>.     "false".     "true".     <INTEGER>.     <DECIMAL>.     ".".     "+".     "-".     "!".     "[".     "(".     ")".     "{".     <ID>

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to use the string builtin. That would not interfere when you have multiple currencies.

```
${record.rate?string("#,##0.00")}
```

[Freemarker builtin string for number](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this
${record.rate?string["#,##0.00"]}